# Git rebase my forked branch on upstream master

Tags: git, github, push, rebase, git-fork

A certain user on Github has a repository with single master branch. I have forked that repository into my own account. I have created a new branch on my own forked repository and have commited some changes to it.

The upstream user has commited changes to their master. I wish to update my master with those changes. Additionally, if I understand `rebase` correctly, I want to `rebase` my branch on that master. I do not want to merge with master because I have not finished developing my branch. Note: The files changed by upstream are different from the files I have changed in my branch, so there should not be an conflicts.

I have tried the following:

I **pulled** changes from the upstream user into my local repo:
`git pull upstream master`

I **pushed** changes from my local master into my forked master:
`git push origin master`

I **rebased** my local branch on my local master:
`git checkout mybranch`
`git rebase master`

I attempted to **push** my rebased local branch to my forked branch:
`git push origin mybranch`

However, I get the following error:

```
To https://github.com/myusername/myforkedrepository.git
 ! [rejected]        mybranch -> mybranch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/myusername/myforkedrepository.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Note that `origin` is my forked repository and `upstream` is the original repositrory.

There is similar question on stackoverflow that suggested a slightly simpler method:

```
git fetch upstream
git rebase upstream/master
```

This did not give any errors, but it has also not pushed anything to my remote fork. After trying the above, I again tried

```
git push origin mybranch
```

but the same error persisted.

How would I go about doing what I want?

Comment: could you provide your **.git/config**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you already published your `mybranch` branch before this.

The solution is simple: Just don't. You want to changed published history, which is never a good idea! This could lead to really ugly bugs for other developers who already based work on your public `mybranch` branch.

---

A technical solution would be: `git push --force origin mybranch` or deleting the remote branch and pushing it again with `git push origin :mybranch` and `git push origin mybranch`

But you don't should do this if `mybranch` is already published.

Comment: Then how should I do it? I want to continue working on my branch, but I want to work with the latest updates from the upstream.

Comment: Just merge the latest changes.

Comment: Oh can I merge `master` into `mybranch` instead of vice versa?

Comment: I really encourage you to read a git tutorial! Good point to start: gitready.com!

Answer (score 4):

This is how I understand your scenario:

```
[upstream repo] ==> [forked repo] <==> [local repo]
   master               master            master
                                          mybranch
```

<sub>The arrows indicate the directional flow of commits.</sub>

And given the above you've asked how do you implement your desired dev flow of keeping your changes always on top.

Overall it is inevitable for the *master* on both the forked and local repos to deviate from the *upstream master*, if they are is to incorporate the changes on the *mybranch* topic branch.

However, when the changes are completely disjoint, as you outline in the question, you can indeed keep your set of changes on top by rebasing and fast-forwarding, when you merge or pull.

```
    0] local master   $ branch mybranch off master 
    1] fork  master   $ git pull --rebase
    2] local master   $ git pull --rebase
    3] local mybranch $ commit commit commit
    4] local mybranch $ git rebase master
```

Repeat 1-4 or just 3-4 as many times as necessary in your dev flow. When you are ready to publish your work to the *forked repo master*, the *upstream master* and the *forked master* will go out of sync, but as long as you've followed 1-4 you should be able to forever keep your changes on top.

```
    5] local master $ git merge --ff-only mybranch
    6] local master $ git push origin
```

And then repeat 1-4 again as many times as necessary.

A word of caution. In order for this to work you may need to reset your branches (or maybe re-clone your repos) to a "clean" state, where you haven't merged and/or pushed yet any of the changes on *mybranch* to a local or forked *master*.